# Maven uploadArchives (aar) to GitLab Maven Repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, gitlab

I am using gradle to generate Android Library Archive (aar) and now want to deploy directly to Git Maven Repo. I have successfully generated it to local file system but problem occurs when I try to deploy to GitLab repo directly.

Note that GitLab repository is public and once I generate Android Library Archive (aar) to local git location (file system) and push it, I can add dependency in other Android projects and it works fine.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'

        //for using HTTP url obtained from GitLab
        classpath 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2'
    }
}
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.groupId = 'com.company.android'
        pom.artifactId = 'androidcommons'
        pom.version = '0.1.1'
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {

            //HTTP url obtained GitLab
            repository(url: "http://beans.infra.company.com/<group>/<project>/raw/maven-repo/releases/")

            pom.groupId = 'com.company.android'
            pom.artifactId = 'androidcommons'

            pom.version = '0.1.1'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle clean install uploadArchives` I get this error:

```
Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://beans.infra.company.com/<group>/<project>/raw/maven-repo/releases/com/company/android/androidcommons/0.1.1/androidcommons-0.1.1.aar does not exist
```

It seems to me that repository url is being treated as File instead of HTTP url. I've looked up at [gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#deployerConfig) and the only information available is that I need to include `'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2'` in dependencies to be treated as HTTP instead of File, which I already am. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that in out projects no `android-maven` plugin was applied nor the `wagon-http` dependency is used. Instead of it `maven` plugin is used. Maybe try this plugin?

Comment: @Opal I'm already using `apply plugin: 'android-maven'` and `classpath 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2'`, are you suggesting the placement is not correct? Can you suggest what should be right placement?

Comment: Hmm.. I was misunderstood. I see that in my projects in my company we don't use `'android-maven'` plugin and `'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2'` dependency. Instead only plain `'maven'` plugin is used and everything works find artifacts are smoothly uploaded.